# How to get the device UUID in ionic framework

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

installed cordova device plugin by :

```
sudo cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

then downloaded ngCordova and included ng-cordova.min.js in to js folder and also included in index.html

next what i did is injected ngCordova as follows

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','ngCordova'])
```

then included in controller as follows

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $ionicPlatform,$cordovaDevice)
but still getting the following errors

ReferenceError: device is not defined
at Object.getUUID (http://localhost:8100/js/ng-cordova.min.js:1:14929)
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:27:26)
at invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11591:17)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11602:23)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14906:28
at updateView (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:42986:30)
at eventHook (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:42933:17)
at Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20605:28)
at $state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:34122:22)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19197:81)
```

Can you now tell me what went wrong?

If is there another way to read the Device UUID show me the direction to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow found out what wrong i was doing... through this question. http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-to-use-ngcordova-device-is-not-defined/11979

when we test on other device which has other platform than cordova supports this happens.
this was a useful discovery for me.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is another way. **You just don't need the ngCordova** for this.

When you add the plugin `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device` it's  loaded to your application and therefore the info you want is at `window.device`.

If you want to get device uuid at anywhere in the code you just need to call `window.device.uuid`.

If you want as soon as the app starts, then use:

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
  console.log( window.device.uuid );
});
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using '> ionic serve', device will be "not defined." Try in an emulator or physical device.

Comment: good point - as this probably won't be very obvious to a lot of people (including myself)

Answer (score 8):

Use [ngCordova and cordova Device plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Device):

> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDevice) {
  var uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Within v2 it works like this:

```
import { Device } from 'ionic-native';
console.log('Device UUID is: ' + Device.uuid);
```

Reference: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/device/

Answer (score 4):

Install:

@ionic-native/core
 @ionic-native/device

[enter link description here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
npm install --save @ionic-native/device
```

Add this plugin to your app's module

```
 // app.module.ts
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    Device
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Usage

```
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

constructor(private device: Device) { }

...

console.log('Device Model is: ' + this.device.model+
  '\n Device UUID is: ' + this.device.uuid+
  '\n Device serial is: ' + this.device.serial+
  '\n Device platform is: ' + this.device.platform+
  '\n Device version is: ' + this.device.version+
  '\n Device manufacturer is: ' + this.device.manufacturer);
```

If won't run change `"import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';"` for `"import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';"`

And `"this.device.uuid"` for "Investigate"

Use these commands for run in browser

```
    ionic build

    ionic cordova platform add browser

    cordova run browser
```

And works ! in these versions

[image]

in Browser

[image]

in Real Device

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `ionic.Platform.device()` in your `platform.ready` function.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function {
  console.log(ionic.Platform.device());// returns an object containing device uuid,version, platform, manufacturer ...
});
```

hope this helps someone :).
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cordova-device-uuid/13652

You may only access cordova plugins within the ionic.Platform.ready() callback function:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $cordovaDevice) {

var init = function () {
  console.log("initializing device");
  try {

    $scope.uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();

  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err.message);
    alert("error " + err.$$failure.message);
  }

};

ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
  init();
});

})
```

This is because Cordova plugins take some more time to load then the web application. The ionic.Platform.ready() callback is triggered as soon Cordova has fully loaded or immediately if it is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have been struggling with this for hours today, install the cordova device plugin with:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`

make sure you also reference the plugin in your config.xml:

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />`