# get device uuid ionic ios app

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app i want to get the device uuid or udid so that i can save it in my database.

for my android app when i run this code in my js file

```
.factory('Service', function($state) {
  var service = {
    login: function(user, new_device_status) {
      if(window.cordova) {
        var params = {
          organization: user.orgCode.$modelValue,
          email: user.email.$modelValue,
          password: user.password.$modelValue,
          device_uuid: window.device.platform == 'Android' ? window.device.uuid : window.device.udid,
          new_device: new_device_status
        };
     }
   }
  }
})
```

it works and returns the uuid of the device but in my ios app when i try this it doesnt work or when i try

```
window.device.udid
```

it still doesnt work in my ios simulator. what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

Add device plugin :

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

In your controller :

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDevice) {
  var uuid = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
});
```

Answer from : [How to get the device UUID in ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466813/how-to-get-the-device-uuid-in-ionic-framework)

**Solution 2 :**

Use IDFVPlugin :

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin.git
```

In your controller :

```
 window.IDFVPlugin.getIdentifier(function(result){ 
    alert(result); 
},function(error){ 
    alert(error); 
});
```

Sources :

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/IDFVPlugin

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-get-iphone-unique-id-udid-in-ionic-framework-script/9575

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

but be aware, the UUID is not the same thing as the UDID.
[Differences between UDID and UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872233/differences-between-udid-and-uuid)

the UUID is the app specific id that changes when you remove the app or update it sometimes even, and the UDID is the unique id from the phone itself.