# How to get device ID in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to find the device ID on which my app is running. I am using angular js and ionic. Is there any way to obtain the device ID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the device UUID in ionic framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466813/how-to-get-the-device-uuid-in-ionic-framework)

Comment: What do you need the device ID for? I ask because searching for Cordova device ID comes back with some optional plugins but depends on what you're trying to use the "ID" for or which particular ID you need depending on your needs

Comment: use this plugin `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device` to get the device ID and for reference to use different methods follow this [link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/)

Comment: @pritam kale check this answer i have already answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717556/retrieve-the-device-token-from-device-using-ionic-framework/36717874#36717874

Comment: Thanks guys....I have used window.device plugin to get the uuid...

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Use AngularJS run**

```
// Calling the rootScope to handle the  ondevice ready
angular.module('myApp').run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          $rootScope.myVariable = "variable value";
          try {
            $rootScope.uuid = device.uuid; //always use device object after deviceready.**
            alert($rootScope.uuid);
            //onapploginx(uuid);
          } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
          }
          // Register the event listener
          document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
      });
  });
}]);
```

**Option 2: Use JS only**

define the onLoad in the body

```
<body id="main_body" ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='DemoController' onload="onLoad()">
```

call addEventListener for device ready and then call the function of onDeviceReady

```
function onLoad() {
  console.log("i am onload");
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
  try {
    var uuid = device.uuid; //always use device object after deviceready.**
    alert("uuidx:",uuid);
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```